# Extracting different data each time while running a selenium script

Tags: python, selenium

I have been running a python selenium script on the following URL :-

http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_1?sort=salesrank&ie=UTF8&rh=n%3A1571277031&page=1&unfiltered=1

And i want to know as to whether each product is a best seller or not. Running the same script sometimes I get a correct results while sometimes I get incorrect results .

Here is the code which i have been working on :

```
import sys
import csv
import os
import time
import urllib

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

count = 1;
serviceurl = 'http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_pg_1?'
for j in range(1,4):

    page = j;
    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({ 'rh':'n:1571277031','page':page,'sort': 'salesrank' , 'unfiltered':'1', 'ie':'UTF8' });
    driver = webdriver.Chrome();
    driver.maximize_window() #For maximizing window
    driver.get(url);
    driver.implicitly_wait(3) #gives an implicit wait for 10 seconds
    while driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") != 'complete':
        pass;

    for i in range(1,17):

        temp = 0;
        print count;
        count+=1;

        try:
            print driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/ul/li[%s]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a/span[1]/span/span"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')

        except Exception as e:
            print "Not a best seller";
            # print e;
```

Here is the output which i get when i run the same script( Correct ans ) :-

```
1
Best seller
2
Best seller
3
Not a best seller
4
Not a best seller
5
Best seller
6
Not a best seller
```

while i also get the following output ( Incorrect ans ) :-

```
1
Not a best seller
2
Not a best seller
3
Not a best seller
4
Not a best seller
5
Not a best seller
6
Not a best seller
```

Any reasons why this is happening ?? and any possible solution to this problem ?

Comment: you should uncomment `print e` it will tell you what failed. BTW, you don't need all those `;`

Comment: @PRMoureu it shows the following error :- selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element...........

But the element is there , lets say i run the script again it wont show error and fetch right ans. Like its the same script , sometimes it is able to locate element , sometimes not . 

Any help ??

P.S. :- thank you for the ; part . I already know that but since i code in c/c++ mostly , so have a habit of putting it

Comment: This is the worst xpath i have seen in my life "print driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/ul/li[%s]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/a/span[1]/span/span"%(i)).text.encode('utf-8')" This will be prone to errors. Don't automated generated XPATHs and learn to create reliable ones

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the products you should use a selector with an id or a class reference (inspect the source to analyze this and extract the class names or id when you can, most of browsers allow to right click on an element to launch inspection) :

```
for i in range(17):
    product = driver.find_element_by_id('result_{}'.format(i))
    try:
        print product.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='sx-badge-text']").text.encode('utf-8')
    except:
        print 'not a best seller'
```

Comment: It still shows the same result . sometimes it fetches correct data , sometimes incorrect

Comment: @GopalChitalia this happen with the same page/url in your test ?

Comment: yes @PRMoureu , it happened with the same url.
and the best-seller class is 
    "a-badge-text"
not
    "sx-badge-text"